# Get a Quartz JobStore implementation in Spring

Tags: spring, quartz-scheduler

Is there any way to get the JobStore implementation created by Spring's SchedulerFactoryBean in a Spring application context ? I'm trying to implement a GUI for the JobStore in my application (doesn't need to be too fancy), but I'm finding that Quartz is nothing short of an epic pain in the **3$#, and just a terrible API. Alternatively, does anyone know of an easy way to create a JobStore implementing bean ? I've found that the ones that come built-in with Quartz aren't very usable / accessible, nor is the one that comes with Spring.  Maybe I'm just missing something. I'm currently running Spring 2.5.6 and Quartz 1.6.0.  I can't upgrade to Spring 3.0 just yet, but I can upgrade the Quartz library if need be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I've been able to tell, there's no really easy way to get an org.quartz.JobStore implementation in Spring that uses both the JobStoreSupport in Quartz, and isn't a PITA to configure, so I just wound up using the Scheduler directly, even though the JobStore has some functions that the Scheduler interface doesn't.